# CUDA shared memory array - odd behavior

Tags: c, cuda, reduce, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

In a CUDA kernel, I have code similar to the following. I am trying to calculate one numerator per thread, and accumulate the numerators over the block to calculate a denominator, and then return the ratio. However, CUDA is setting the value of `denom` to whatever value is calculated for `numer` by the thread in the block with the largest `threadIdx.x`, rather than the sum of the `numer` value calculated across all the threads in the block. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
extern __shared__ float s_shared[];

float numer = //calculate numerator

s_shared[threadIdx.x] = numer;
s_shared[blockDim.x] += numer;
__syncthreads();

float denom = s_shared[blockDim.x];
float result = numer/denom;
```

`result` should always be between 0 and 1 and should sum to 1 across the block, but instead it is equal to 1.0 for every thread where `threadIdx.x` is the maximum, and some other value not confined to the range for the other threads in the block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not synchronizing the summing properly to the `blockDim.x` location.  None of the threads are waiting to see what others have written before adding their sum.  Sort of like

1. Everyone reads zero,
2. goes home, calculates zero + `numer`.
3. Everyone writes zero+`numer` to the memory location

The high threadId wins b/c it has a high likelihood of acting last, I suppose.

What you want to do instead, in order to do a quick sum, is to do a binary sum on
`s_shared[threadIdx.x]`

1. everyone writes their `numer`
2. half the threads calculate sums of pairs and write those to a new location
3. a quarter of the threads calculate the sums of pairs of pairs, and write those to a new location
4. etc
5. until you just have one thread and one sum

This takes O(n) work and O(log n) time.

Comment: Just to make a note of this, the logic here is known as a reduction. There are a few samples of this in the cuda sdk. See: cuda-sdk/C/src/reduction/reduction_kernel.cu

Comment: The sample can be found [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/e612904184446c81e4d5beac8755081f9662cca0/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/reduction/reduction_kernel.cu#L191-L224) now.